# How does my browser detect my location, even via proxy?

Tags: privacy, proxy

How does my browser detect my location even via proxy?

I have [tried this code](http://www.w3schools.com/htmL/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation_map) via VPN and got the same result as without it. According to the [specification](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) my browser should detect it from:

> Common sources of location information include Global Positioning
>   System (GPS) and location inferred from network signals such as IP
>   address, RFID, WiFi and Bluetooth MAC addresses, and GSM/CDMA cell
>   IDs, as well as user input.

So, I proxied my IP. I have no GPS on my PC and do not use WiFi or GSM either. How did this happen? Note that it is accurate to the street.

Comment: There's always your local timezone. Your browser knows that. It gives no information about your latitude, but it does put your longitude inside a fairly narrow range. Plus, some timezones touch only one or a few countries, so that nails it down as long as it is assumed you are not at sea.

Comment: How fine is the location? Is it specific to a 10 mile radius? 100 mile radius? City, country?

Comment: Which browser? What platform?

Comment: @FlorinCoada very accuracy, show my street.

Comment: @lorenzog FireFox and IE in Win7

Comment: @M.R. you might want to update your question including the details from the comments so it is easier to answer.

Comment: My understanding is that the geolocation functionality is provided by google. Check here how chrome does it : https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142065?hl=en  . So what they do is take LOCAL information about your network, so the fact that there's a proxy won't affect it as data is gathered from the machine and it happens before the proxy.  If you want to block it you'll have to block the location services in both Firefox and IE.

Comment: I have no wifi on my desktop pc. use ADSL2 connection

Answer (score 2):

Several proxies add extra headers to a session which leaks info such as the [`X-Forwarded-For`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) header which includes the origin IP address.

Since OP question states there is no GPS/GSM network involved, then one can assume this is running on a desktop, laptop, or WiFi tablet, therefore the location data is likely being acquired by geoip data related to the IP address in the X-Forwarded-For header.

**Testing headers**

```
- login to a remote shell outside the proxy
- exec netcat -l -p 8080
- on local browse to remote:8080 with proxy enabled then read the stdout on remote
```

This also tests for additional data that may be sent. `tcpdump` can also be run on the remote server.

Comment: Considering OP post states he's proxing from a desktop environment ( ie no GPS chip, non gsm network) and does not state any WiFi networks involved let alone the proxy would eliminate anyways and given I ran the same app in the same type of environment which produced the same results as OP, one can conclude that the location info is based off the geoip data related to his x-forward-for header passed by the proxy.

Comment: I completely agree with you, but you are speculating that the x-fwd-for headers are the problem and even phrase your question as 'something to check'. This could, in fact, be the answer, but it is still speculation at this point. If this was a comment to get the OP to check this - THEN you have a definitive answer. That's all I'm saying.

Comment: I like it. I polished some of the wording to remove the confusion at the end.

Comment: I don't think it's x-forwaded-for because i use an extension on Firefox that can fake that with random ips and they still can track my location somehow

Comment: I don't think this is the case. If you look at the code the OP posted it calls `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()`. If you want to test your hypothesis of the X-Forwarded-For header you could use Tor and see what happens. You might need to use a Tor SOCKS with a regular browser as Tor's browser bundle might have that disabled.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633879/how-does-web-browser-geolocation-work) and [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213410/how-does-html5-geolocation-work) might be relevant for you. In particular, quoting from [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3C_Geolocation_API)

> The most common sources of location information are IP address, Wi-Fi
>   and Bluetooth MAC address, radio-frequency identification (RFID),
>   Wi-Fi connection location, or device Global Positioning System (GPS)
>   and GSM/CDMA cell IDs. The location is returned with a given accuracy
>   depending on the best location information source available.

Which means, related to your question, that your browser might acquire that data from sources available on your operating system rather than relying on a web resource.

Comment: This link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213410/how-does-html5-geolocation-work  goes into a bit more detail about how it works.